# Not able to install lotion via npm

Tags: node.js, hyper

i tried doing this in hyper

```
<npm install lotion --save>
```

But i got following error

> npm ERR! errno 1 
>  npm ERR!
>   tendermint-node@3.5.0 preinstall: 'rm -f ./bin/tendermint && touch
>   ./bin/tendermint'> 
>  npm ERR! exit status 1> 
> npm ERR!
>   
> npm ERR! failed at the tendermint-node@3.5.0 preinstall script.

Comment: Did you try to install lotion in another location? From what kind of console do you run the npm command?

Comment: yes i did. It just doesn't work. I am using hyper to run npm command

Comment: Hm, then I don't see any reason why it can't run the `rm -f ./bin/tendermint && touch ./bin/tendermint'` command properly...

Answer (score 0):

You can apply two solutions.

1. Remove Package-lock.json file. and try to install it
2. Use -f `npm install lotion --save -f`

Comment: for removing package-lock.json i used <npm config set package-lock false>

Comment: then to install lotion i used <npm install lotion --save -f>